# Delete file based on author name in commit

Tags: groovy, jgit

My code delete just files which parse to Jenkins name in the file. I would like to delete file based on the author (Jenkins) in the last commit. What is the best solution for that?

```
def changelogPath = "C:\\test"
def PackID = "test"

def delete(String changelogPath, String PackID) {
    String folderPath = "$changelogPath"+ "\\" + "$PackID"
    new File(folderPath).eachFile(FileType.FILES) { file ->
      if (file.name.contains('Jenkins')) file.delete()
}

delete(changelogPath, PackID)
```

Comment: check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23151837/get-file-owner-metadata-information-with-java

Answer (score 0):

In order to find all files that have been changed with a certain commit, you need a diff of that commit with its predecessor.

You can let JGit compute a list of DiffEntries like this:

```java
ObjectReader reader = git.getRepository().newObjectReader();
CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
ObjectId oldTree = git.getRepository().resolve( "HEAD^{tree}" ); 
oldTreeIter.reset( reader, oldTree );
CanonicalTreeParser newTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
ObjectId newTree = git.getRepository().resolve( "HEAD~1^{tree}" );
newTreeIter.reset( reader, newTree );

DiffFormatter df = new DiffFormatter( new ByteArrayOutputStream() );
df.setRepository( git.getRepository() );
List<DiffEntry> entries = df.scan( oldTreeIter, newTreeIter );
```

Each `DiffEntry` has a path that denotes the file which was added, changed, or deleted. The path is relative to the root of the working directory of the repository. Actually, there is an oldPath and newPath, see the [JavaDoc](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/diff/DiffEntry.html) which one to use when.

See also here for a general overview of JGit's diff API: http://www.codeaffine.com/2016/06/16/jgit-diff/

Comment: There's no easier way ? For example use `class PersonIdent` and `getAuthor` method ?

Comment: The author and committer is the same for all changed files in a commit

Comment: If I understand correctly, for me it will work. If author in last commit is Jenkins -> Delete this file. So how use `getAuthor` in if statement to delete ?

Comment: Not sure what relation there is between 'Jenkins' and the file to delete. However, to get the author of a commit, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820282/get-the-latest-commit-in-a-repository-with-jgit. The `RevCommit` hold all the metadata about a commit.